# Flipping an animation controller view property value in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to flip the `progress` value  of an `AnimatedIcon`. For example:

```
icon: AnimatedIcon(
  icon: AnimatedIcons.close_menu,
  progress: _controller.view,
),
```

Right now the icon animation is backwards for what I need. So when I'm expecting `_controller.view` to be `0.0` it's actually showing `1.0`.

I tried:

```
progress: _controller.view == 1.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0
```

but `_controller.view` is an `Animation<double>` and not just a `<double>`.

How can I set `progress` to a hard coded value?

Comment: Put all your widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`Tween`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/Tween-class.html) to create an animation that transforms the controller's range of values `[0.0, 1.0]` to an inverted range `[1.0, 0.0]` using `Tween.animate`. For example,

```
// create your tween.
final tween = Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0);

// apply it to a controller to create an animation.
final animation<double> = tween.animate(controller);

AnimatedIcon(
  icon: AnimatedIcons.close_menu,
  progress: animation,
);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I find using `ReverseAnimation` is more intuitive for me

```
icon: AnimatedIcon(
  icon: AnimatedIcons.close_menu,
  progress: ReverseAnimation(_controller),
),
```